# Cannot use a scalar value as an array while using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, pdo

I am trying to input data from a JSON API into a MySQL DB but I have an error.

This is the error.

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom\example\scraping\example_scraping_imdb.php on line 8
>
> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom\example\scraping\example_scraping_imdb.php on line 9
>
> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom\example\scraping\example_scraping_imdb.php on line 10
>
> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom\example\scraping\example_scraping_imdb.php on line 11
>
> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom\example\scraping\example_scraping_imdb.php on line 12
>
> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom\example\scraping\example_scraping_imdb.php on line 13
>
> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom\example\scraping\example_scraping_imdb.php on line 14
>
> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom\example\scraping\example_scraping_imdb.php on line 15

Al those lines are the bind param statements in the PHP code.

Here is the code that I use (The JSON objects are nested):

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wtd','root','');
$jsondata = file_get_contents('https://hugo.events/genre/pop/next/200/100');
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into events values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $row['hits']['hits']['_id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $row['hits']['hits']['fields']['name']);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $row['hits']['hits']['fields']['start']);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $row['hits']['hits']['fields']['venue.location']);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $row['hits']['hits']['fields']['description']);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $row['hits']['hits']['fields']['header']);
    $stmt->bindParam(7, $row['hits']['hits']['fields']['logo']);
    $stmt->bindParam(8, $row['hits']['hits']['fields']['genres']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

EDIT: Sample of JSON data:

https://ghostbin.com/paste/437q7

Hope someone has a sollution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am pretty new to PDO so I don't understand what they mean there

Comment: Instead of saying "you have to go to this URL", why not post a sample of the data?

Comment: Edited it. It has an example niw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark
>   placeholder in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the
>   statement. Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as
>   a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that
>   PDOStatement::execute() is called.

You need to create list of independent variables to bind them into statement:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $v1 = $row['hits']['hits']['_id'];
    $v2 = $row['hits']['hits']['fields']['name'];
    $v3 = $row['hits']['hits']['fields']['start'];
    ...
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $v1);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $v2);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $v3);
    ...
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Or you can try to use [bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $row['hits']['hits']['_id']);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $row['hits']['hits']['fields']['name']);
    $stmt->bindValue(3, $row['hits']['hits']['fields']['start']);
    ... 
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

**UPDATE** After reviewing json you provided I have not that many words to say.
   I have no idea what is your expectations are, but you definetely can not do `foreach ($data as $row) {` against that data.

You can play a bit with your data [here](http://ideone.com/bdzeyH)

So to get that `_id` you should call:

```
$data[1]['hits']['hits'][1]['_id'];
```

And to get `fields` you need to:

```
$data[1]['hits']['hits'][0]['fields'];
```

Probably you use data different from what you did post here.

**UPDATE 2** SO is not to develop for you. Try to do your homework first next time please. But [here](http://ideone.com/VWhbEi) is what you are looking for I guess:

```
foreach ($data[1]['hits']['hits'] as $row) {
    $v1 = $row['_id'];
    $v2 = $row['fields']['name'][0];
    $v3 = $row['fields']['start'][0];
    ....
}
```

Comment: It got rid of the error but now I have a new error: Notice: Undefined index: _id in

Comment: So now you should check your array data returned from json. Or probably just `$row['hits']['hits']['fields']['_id']`

Comment: The _id is not in the fields object. It shows them for all the rows

Comment: provide complete json example. The one you posted is not complete to discuss.

Comment: Added a ghostbin link. Json was too long

Comment: @stevensmith check update

Comment: But this only points to the first array right? How can I point it to all the arrays?

Comment: @stevensmith check update please

Comment: Thanks everything works